# LazyInitializationException when using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency

I keep getting an error when trying to fetch some objects from the database:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException (LazyInitializationException.java:19)     - could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

But I only get the error when using threads. Our application structure method call flow is as:

```
FacadeImpl.saveRV() -->

@Transactional
@ParallelContext
BusinessImpl.validateEntry() -->

BusinessImpl.getOpMap() -->

@ParallelTask
DAOImpl.getMEFilter()
```

I get the LazyInitializationException when trying to access a field of the fetched entities, defined as:

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to PtoConex
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDN_PTO_CONEX", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private PtoConex progTptoConex;
```

However, if I remove the `@ParallelContext` annotation from the declaration of `BusinessImpl.validateEntry()` and `@ParallelTask` from `DAOImpl.getMEFilter()`, I don't have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Hibernate session and the entities loaded from that session are not thread safe. If you try accessing them from different thread you will run into this kind of "weird" exceptions.

Most of the time mixing transactions with concurrency is also a bad idea.

Comment: +1. Also, even if they were thread-safe, the transaction, and the associated session, that has been started by the business service, has already been closed when the parallel thread tries to lazy-load the association.

Comment: But that's not my decission. Also, I don't think I'm accessing the entities from a different thread.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing (I don't know `@ParallelContext` and `@ParallelTask`), could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @JBNizet: Why has the transaction been closed? It's still under the stack of `validateEntry()`, which is `@Transactional`. I thought until the whole method doesn't finish, the session wouldn't be closed.

Comment: `ParallelTask` defines methods that will be invoked as threads, concurrently. `ParallelContext` defines the context where threads will be used, where the `ParallelTask` methods will be called.

Comment: I don't know what these ParallelTask and ParallelContext annotations do (I've not been able to find their javadoc), but if I understand correctly, they cause the task to be executed in a parallel thread. So I'm assuming that calling the method annotated with ParallelTask submits the task to another thread and returns immediately. Each thread has its own stack, and its own ThreadLocals. So the transaction started by the service doesn't "cover" the parallel task. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So, just out of curiosity, since I can't change that. What would be your alternative to Hibernate + Threads?

Comment: Could you explain with more details what you're trying to do? Why do you need concurrency in the first place?